# Reading results from PHP Facebook Graph api SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am trying to get a list of all the names & id of people actually going to an event I create. Getting the list using the php graph api for facebook was the easy part and seems to work.

Code (php) the get the data:

> //GET ATTENDING
>
> ```
>     $getattending = "/" . $event_id . "/attending?fields=name,id";
>
>     $req_events = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', $getattending);
>     $req_response = $req_events->execute();
>     $data_array = $req_response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
>
>     $counter = array_map("count", $data_array);
>     $count = $counter['data'];
>
>     echo "Attending: $count<BR>";
>
>    echo "<PRE>";
>    print_r($data_array);
>    echo "</PRE>";
> ```

The result:

> Array (
>
> ```
> [data] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [name] => Thierry Martens
>                 [id] => 788923242
>             )
>
>         [1] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [name] => Lisa Mario Laurier
>                 [id] => 708876902536391
>             )
>
>         [2] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [name] => Ramy Mahfoudhi
>                 [id] => 735036479911364
>             )
>
>         [3] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [name] => Jeremy Verriest Duroisin
>                 [id] => 783108468420824
>             )
>
>         [4] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [name] => Jonas En Svetlana Laurier
>                 [id] => 773139856081632
>             )
>
>         [5] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [name] => Maxime Demerliere
>                 [id] => 849400761761008
>             )
>
>         [6] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [name] => Jeremy Beauchamp
>                 [id] => 10204174155667109
>             )
>
>         [7] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [name] => Sari Jens Delcourte Delusinne
>                 [id] => 10204086515874904
>             )
>
>         [8] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [name] => Pieter Marysse
>                 [id] => 10204911283045115
>             )
>
>         [9] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [name] => Patrick Vanden Bosschelle
>                 [id] => 10202907209181148
>             )
>
>     )
> ```

BUT i am having problems to actually gather the data itsels; i simply need the name and the id in simple array or list so i can use it in the rest of the script. Any ideas Anyone?

My second question is the php graph api seems to have a "/eventnr/attending" thing for graph 2.1; showing nr attendants to your event in question; but when i actually call it i get an error stating i need to use graph 2.1 while i uploaded the latest php sdk and can't seem to find a way to change that version. This question is not as important as the one above; but if it works i would need less code :)

Hope you guys can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

!!!! GOT IT !!!!

Did look some further on here and the solutions seems to be pretty easy:

> ```
> for ($x = 0; $x <= $count; $x++)
>         {
>         $names[$x] = $data_array['data'][$x]->name;
>         $ids[$x] = $data_array['data'][$x]->id;
>         }
> ```

Displays:

> $names array:
>
> Array ( [0] => Thierry Martens [1] => Lisa Mario Laurier [2] => Ramy
>   Mahfoudhi [3] => Jeremy Verriest Duroisin [4] => Jonas En Svetlana
>   Laurier [5] => Maxime Demerliere [6] => Jeremy Beauchamp [7] => Sari
>   Jens Delcourte Delusinne [8] => Pieter Marysse [9] => Patrick Vanden
>   Bosschelle [10] => )
>
> $ids array:
>
> Array ( [0] => 788923242 [1] => 708876902536391 [2] => 735036479911364
>   [3] => 783108468420824 [4] => 773139856081632 [5] => 849400761761008
>   [6] => 10204174155667109 [7] => 10204086515874904 [8] =>
>   10204911283045115 [9] => 10202907209181148 [10] => )

Answer (score 0):

It's like:

```
$dataArray = $data_array['data'];
$firstPerson = new $dataArray[0];
echo $firstPerson->name;
echo $firstPerson->id;
```

Maybe you need this, though:

```
foreach($data_array['data'] as $a){
  $o = new $a; $names[] = $o->name; $ids[] = $o->id;
}
// $names is Array of names
// $ids in Array of ids
```

Comment: Not working  ;( I ll edit my frist code and add the code i use to get the data; might be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

I added your code but result is the following (empty arrays)

added code:

> ```
>     foreach($data_array['data'] as $a)
>             {
>             $o = new $a; $names[] = $o->name; $ids[] = $o->id;
>             }
>
>     echo "FIRST ELEMENT - \$data_array['data'][0]: <BR>";
>     print_r($data_array['data'][0]); echo "<BR><BR>";
>     echo "\$names array: <BR>";
>     print_r($names); echo "<BR><BR>";
>     echo "\$ids array: <BR>";
>     print_r($ids); echo "<BR><BR>";
> ```

Result of the echo & print_r:

> FIRST ELEMENT - $data_array['data'][0]:
>
> ```
>     stdClass Object ( [name] => Thierry Martens [id] => 788923242 )
> ```
>
> $names array:
>
> ```
>     Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => )
> ```
>
> $ids array:
>
> ```
>     Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => )
> ```